# Record user's ip address everytime user loggin in - PHP

Tags: php, ip, ip-address

Here are my codes from the login page. I want to be able to count how many times have been using my website and also where they logged in from. I am able to do the count, but not the ipaddress.

In the table, I want it show each user data like this

These are the columns in my table. USERNAME, LAST LOGGED IN, TIMES LOGGING IN, IPADDRESS, IPADDRESS1, IPADDRESS, ...... IPADDRESS10. I have created all 10 different ip address columns ( I am not really sure how to make the followings looks like they are in the table, so I am really sorry )

USERNAME  |    LAST LOGGED IN    |  TIMES LOGGING IN  |   IPADDRESS   |  IPADDRESS1   |  IPADDRESS2 ......  |  IPADDRESS10

IHOP      |  21-12-2012 8.59PM   |         5          |  80.81.82.83  |  80.81.82.82  |  80.81.82.83

Every time a new ip address was used to log in from the same user, the ip address will be record into the table. Each user has up to 10 different ip addresses. The table is from my first thought, so I am not really sure if it's the best way to show them in the table or not, so please also give me a recommendation.

How do I add these ip addresses in to the table? I am not really sure how to separate each ip address column. When I got the new ip address, it just keeps overwriting the old ip address.

Thank you very much.

```
var $HOST = "website.com";  
var $USERNAME = "username"; 
var $PASSWORD = "password"; 
var $DBNAME = "database";   

function authenticate($username, $password) {

$Auth = new auth();
$detail = $Auth->authenticate($username, $password);

    if (ereg("'", $username)) 
    {
        return "invalid username";
    }

    if (ereg("'", $password)) 
    {
        return "invalid password";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname='$username' AND passwd=MD5('$password') AND status <> 'inactive'";

    $UpdateRecords = "UPDATE user SET lastlogin = NOW(), logincount = logincount + 1 WHERE uname='$username'";
    $connection = mysql_connect($this->HOST, $this->USERNAME, $this->PASSWORD);

    $SelectedDB = mysql_select_db($this->DBNAME);
    $result = mysql_query($query); 

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if ($numrows == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    */
    else {
        $Update = mysql_query($UpdateRecords);
        return $row;
    }
```

Comment: There are a lot more ways to inject SQL into a query. Testing (with deprecated `ereg`) for single quotes is not sufficient. I suggest you migrate to prepared statements and drop the use of `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: "Each user has up to 10 different ip addresses" well no, user does not = ip. I could use a different ip for every request for every file on you site, let alone a "visit". Also any number of people could share one ip

Comment: @Dagon I'm guessing he just wants to log the last X IP addresses used, not use them to identify anyone in particular.

Comment: @Jack, perhaps, there are still people that think ip="user". Hopefully piamboon will respond some time.

Comment: I am sorry if I confuse anyone. I want to be able to see where each user log in from up to 10 different ipaddresses, but I am not really sure how to record them in each ip address column.

Comment: ok but why, what are you using the data for?

Comment: I am just trying to see if that user allows someone else to use his account or maybe that account got hacked.

Comment: well the point with what i wrote above, the ip will not tell you that. as ip != person.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a better idea to have a separate table with (USERNAME | IPADDRESS | TIME) columns. That way, you will be able to store more effectively (and easily) different IP adress for a given user.
Then, you'll have to choose an algorithm to retain these informations (keep first 10 different IP adress ? keep last 10 ?...)

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your suggestion. I am looking to keep the first 10 ip addresses and record each one of them in each ip address column. Every time I try the new ip address keeps replacing the one.

Answer (score 0):

uSe separate table with userid, ipaddress, logged_in_date_time. And everytime they login, check their IP address. Use to GROUP By ipaddress in your query and see if there are 10 different ip for that user. Now if user has same IP then let him in...if the IP is different and there are more than 10 IP's dont let him in.

**Edit:**

But your requirement is not handy in users' view. I use ADSL connection and my IP gets changed frequently, so its not user friendly that I m not being able to login to your system if your database has my 10 different IPs. Also if my system is in network, 100 of users might access your system with same IP.

Use prepared statement, PDO or at least mysqli functions for application security. mysql functions are depreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion I will try putting the data in different table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use two tables. One for storing the user's **username**, **password**, **last login time** and **login count**, and another for storing the IP Addresses of the users. You can store the **username/userid**, **ip address**, and **login timestamp** of the user every time the user logs in.

That way, if you want to only store the last 10 ip addresses of the user, you can just filter the sql search to only show the ip addresses of that specific user, then replace the earliest ip address entry with the latest one, so you will always have the last 10 entries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion I will try putting the data in different table.